# Alterar o estilo, atributo "display", de uma canvas no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho uma função Javascript que pega uma canvas vazia e preenche ela. Só que, como em um primeiro momento eu não quero exibir o canvas, eu setei o estilo dela, no atributo display como "none". Agora, eu alterar o display para block (em tempo de execução). Como eu poderia fazer isso no Javascript?

Essa é a canvas no meu html:

```
<canvas class="canvasCentral" id="bordas" width="400" height="500">

    </canvas>
```

O estilo aplicado à canvas é a classe "canvasCentral" de um arquivo css vinculado ao meu html:

```
.canvasCentral{
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        border:3px solid #D8D8D8;
        border-radius: 20px;
        display:none

    }
```

Como eu poderia, no Javascript, em tempo de execução alterar o display da canvas para block?

Comment: O que quer dizer com tempo de execução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar pelo id

```
document.getElementById('bordas').style.display = "block";
```

Ou pela classe (se você quiser alterar para todos os elementos que usam essa classe)

```
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("canvasCentral");
elementos.forEach(alteraDisplay)

function alteraDisplay(item, index) {
    item.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Entendi. Deu certo. Outra coisa: ao passar a função "alteraDisplay" para o forEach, a forEach tem setado como seus parâmetros os da alteraDisplay, certo?

Comment: Então, o `forEach` tem como callback uma função cujos parâmetros são o `current_value`, o `index` (opcional) e o `array` (opcional), por isso que a função alteraDisplay tem como parâmetros de entrada o `item` (que vai receber o current_value do callback) e o `index` (que vai receber o index do callback). Na verdade ela poderia receber apenas o item, porque é a única coisa que estamos usando nesse caso.

Para saber mais, veja a documentação do MDN:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach